# Reset an Alert monitor condition from "fired"

Tags: azure-cli, azure-monitoring

I have created an alert and it fired once. Now the monitor condition of the alert is "Fired". How can I reset it now from CLI considering I want to restrict portal access? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any script? If tried, Could you share it here? @Parth Sekar

Comment: The Alert Management module helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This [Alerts Management module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.alertsmanagement/?view=azps-9.6.0) has useful commands for managing alerts. The below one helped me update the state of the alert.

```
   Update-AzAlertState -AlertId "afbf1b3a-0a6c-4f19-9c9b-644ccd7b1529" -State "Closed"
```